# why does ng-table shows data but no design on pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I was able to display the data but why does the pagination has no design at all. Even if i included the ng-table.min.css in my index page.
The tutorial that i following is [this](http://tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-table-pagination-with-ng-table) link

error in Pagination:

[image]

Here is my code in my Controller:

```
 var module = angular.module('myApp.controller', ['myApp.service','ngTable']);
 module.controller('HomeController', ['HomeService', '$window','$filter', 'ngTableParams',
 function (HomeService, $window, $filter, ngTableParams) {

    var self = this;
    self.EmpData = [];

    HomeService.getAllEmployeesTable().then(onSuccess, onError);

    function onSuccess(response) {
        self.EmpData = response.data;
        self.usersTable = new ngTableParams({   page: 1, count: 4}, 
            {
                total: self.EmpData.length,
                getData: function ($defer, params) {

                    self.data = self.EmpData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    $defer.resolve(self.data);
                }});}
```

And in my Partial html i have this code:

```
<div class="card-body">
 <table ng-table ="home.usersTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ContactId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="rods in home.data">
            <td>{{rods.contactId}}</td>
            <td>{{rods.name}}</td>
            <td>{{rods.email}}</td>
            <td>{{rods.address}}</td>
            <td>{{rods.telephone}}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="edit" role="button"
                ng-click="home.Edit(rods)">Edit</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger"
                    ng-click="home.deleteEmployee($index)">Delete</button>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="create" role="button">Add</a>
 <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"
    ng-click="home.test()">test</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please share your complete code so that we can see the files you have referenced in your HTML. The pagination styles could be because you havent added bootstrap CSS . Please add this on top of HTML : <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"

Comment: here is my index.html: http://pasted.co/de2b96bc ... I already referenced bootstrap locally btw. @VijayMenon

Comment: i added the online bootstrap cdn and it surprisingly works :D. that's weird, could that be because i use the .min version?

Comment: i think its because i use version 4 of bootstrap. if i use 3.3.7 my pagination have a design,.

Comment: if i use version 3.3.7 my ui design got destroyed, but pagination has a design. lmao

Comment: I have the same problem. what should I do? @LogronJ